# convert an array of complex numbers into real number

Tags: python, arrays, histogram

I am using the networkx package, and I am looking at the adjacency spectrum of the graph (which consists only of real values since my adjacency matrix is symmetric), but when I use

```
data = nx.adjacency_spectrum(G)
```

I get back an array of complex numbers, but all of them have zero complex part. I used

```
data.sort()
plt.plot(list(range(0,len(data))), data,'ro')
```

to get a nice graph of them, but when I tried to do the histogram, using

```
plt.hist(data)
```

it gives me an error:

> TypeError: Cannot cast ufunc subtract output from dtype('complex128') to dtype('float64') with casting rule 'same_kind'

Does anyone know a way to get around this so I can plot a histogram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
plt.hist(data.astype(float))
```